# How do I change the underlying distribution in garch.sim?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, distribution

I want to change the underlying distribution for my garch.sim function, but I get the following error : *could not find function "rnd"*

I would like to change it to either t or chi-squared distribution, as the default one is normal from a normal distribution. The below code is trying to mimic the normal distribution with sd = 4, but it gives the same error. The source code does not give additional hint in my opinion to solve the issue.

The code itself:
`u_garch <-garch.sim(alpha = c(0.01,0.3), beta = 0.69,n = 251,rnd = rnorm(351,sd = 4),ntrans = 100)`